# PDO won't return result even if query is valid

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I used PDO hundreds of times but now I'm very frustrated - everything seems ok for me, I must be missing something... I use PGSql and PDO. Passing query to PgAdmin 3 and running it - no problem! But calling it from PDO is a different story.

My code:

```
(...checking if $name is null and so on...)

$query = "SELECT 
            *
            FROM
            out.city
            WHERE 
            city_name ILIKE ?";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        try{
            $res = $stmt->execute(array("'".$name."'"));
            $ret = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
(... rest of try-catch block...)
```

Problem is that `$res` returns boolean (true) instead of object. It results in error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object
```

I've tried few methods of how to put `$name` inside query - using question mark, bind or just joining the strings (I know, bad way). None of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be prepare handle (object) only, replace `$res->` with `$stmt->`,

```
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I'm blind. In the middle of the week. I feel bad with this. Thanks!

Comment: And there is no need for `$res`.

Comment: @hjpotter92 there is reason for `$res`. Even if you use try-catch, sometimes query might fail without throwing exception. For me it's good practice to always write `$res` and return it on inserts and updates, because if something fails, I can always rollback transaction.

Comment: @ex3v got an example?

Comment: For example when you're working on a huge and old project where someone forgot to add `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` to connection string, or ORM sometimes won't throw exceptions because of bugs. It's a safelock.